# Count number of repeated character in a given string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I count the number of occurrences of repeated $ character in the given strings.

For ex:

1. String = '$$$$ABC$$$DE$$$' --> Answer is 4,3,3
2. String = '###$$%%ANE$$$$$' --> Answer is 2,5

I have no idea how to do it so did not do any attempts.

Thanks for your help.

For Reproducing:

1. DDL and Inserts:

```
Create table xyz(text varchar(200));
Insert into xyz values('$$$$ABC$$$DE$$$');
Insert into xyz values('###$$%%ANE$$$$$');
```

2. What I need to do: Count the repeated number of '$'
3. Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.

   text = '$$$$ABC$$$DE$$$' --> Answer is 4,3,3
   text = '###$$%%ANE$$$$$' --> Answer is 2,5
4. SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Please post what you have tried thus far.

Comment: *"SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5"* Why haven't you patched your SQL Server in almost 2 years..? There have been multiple bug and security fixes. If you're not updating your applications, I dread to think how out of date your operating system is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution. It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

It is based on use of the `TRANSLATE()` function, and XML and XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('$$$$ABC$$$DE$$$'), --> Answer is 4,3,3
('###$$%%ANE$$$$$'); --> Answer is 2,5
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
        , REPLACE(TRANSLATE(tokens, '$', SPACE(1)),' ','') AS JunkCharacters
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
, REPLACE(TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' +
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE(tokens, TRIM(JunkCharacters), SPACE(LEN(TRIM(JunkCharacters)))), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
        .query('
        for $x in /root/r[text()]
        return data(string-length($x))
        ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS CleansedTokensCounter
FROM cte;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| ID |     tokens      | JunkCharacters | CleansedTokensCounter |
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | $$$$ABC$$$DE$$$ | ABCDE          |                 4,3,3 |
|  2 | ###$$%%ANE$$$$$ | ###%%ANE       |                   2,5 |
+----+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**We can do this with a number of steps:**

- **We use a tally/numbers table to shred the string** into individual characters. The tally is calculated on the fly with a couple of cross-joins and `ROW_NUMBER`
- **We then calculate a grouping ID** for each group of characters, using a standard gaps-and-islands technique: a windowed sum of each starting row
- Filter down to the character we want, group it by ID and return a count of rows in each group.

This returns a new row for every group of `$` characters

```sql
Create table xyz(text varchar(200));
Insert into xyz values('$$$$ABC$$$DE$$$');
Insert into xyz values('###$$%%ANE$$$$$');

WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    -- you can allow for larger strings with more cross-joins
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L1 )

SELECT
    xyz.[text],
    r.numRepetitions
FROM xyz
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT numRepetitions = COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP(LEN(xyz.[text]))
            thisChar = SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum, 1),
            groupId = SUM(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 OR SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum, 1) <> SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum - 1, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
               OVER (ORDER BY rownum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM Nums
        ORDER BY rownum
    ) AS chars
    WHERE thisChar = '$'
    GROUP BY groupId
) AS r;
```

If you want a single comma-separated list of row-counts, you need to subquery again

```sql
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT numRepetitions = STRING_AGG(CAST(numRepetitions AS varchar(10)), ',')
    FROM (
        SELECT numRepetitions = COUNT(*)
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP(LEN(xyz.[text]))
                thisChar = SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum, 1),
                groupId = SUM(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 OR SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum, 1) <> SUBSTRING(xyz.[text], rownum - 1, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                   OVER (ORDER BY rownum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
            FROM Nums
            ORDER BY rownum
        ) AS chars
        WHERE thisChar = '$'
        GROUP BY groupId
    ) AS groups
) AS r;
```